# How To Set Up A Conditional Probability Problem?

Tags: probability

We have to use this online program for my math class, and I got these two problems wrong three times, so I can no longer try and it is counted as wrong, but it will not actually give me the solutions so I can know what I did wrong. Can anyone show me how to do these two?

Marciano draws five cards from a 52-card deck.  Calculate the probability of each given event.

There is exactly one face card, given three of the cards are red

Three cards are Aces, given one of the Aces was removed from the deck

Comment: Show us the work that you have done so far. It's ok if you get it wrong, we will correct you.

Comment: We dont actually solve it, its an online thing that has a few multiple choice answers for each question, where you have to pick each step. I honestly have no idea how to go about solving it.

Comment: But at least you can start as follows: how many ways are there to draw five cards  from $52$ so that  three are red? Remember the other two are black. The questions might be multiple choice, but unless you solve this question I'm not sure you can guess the answer intelligently, you still have to work through it.

Comment: The other 2 need not be black, they only said that 3 of them were red, they didn't say that exactly 3 of them would be red.